# Pure SQL way to save query output in Spark-sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to save query result to file using pure SQL form?
I understand that we can do it easily using java or scala api. But I am looking for pure SQL solution which can be executed via Spark-sql CLI directly.

Answer (score 0):

Create table is the closest thing:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table
USING format                   -- some format
LOCATION '/path/to/location'
AS SELECT * FROM some_view     -- some query
```

It is not fully equivalent to simple save methods, as it uses metastore.

Comment: When you say metastore, does it create entry in hive metastore?